# PhoneGap JQueryMobile getting Dynamic content

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, cordova

how can i get all the records from my database to be shown in my application , i wrote a php file that retrieve all the records. but then how can i call it in PhoneGap + JQuery mobile. does the normal .ajax() method work in Jquery mobile . if yes , can someone show me a code snippet for that WITH THE JQUERY MOBILE initialization

Comment: the .ajax() will work in jQuery mobile.  jQuery mobile is built on top of jQuery so all jQuery methods should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the .ajax() method within jQuery Mobile. You can do something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
...
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "",
            url: "",
            data: "",
            success: function(){}
        });
    });
</script>
...

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">...</div>
    <div data-role="content">...</div>
    <div data-role="footer">...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You will need to change this to fit your needs but this should allow you to get the records from your database and display them (or whatever you need to do with them).

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is my code and its not working

 <script>
    $(function() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", ajaxCall, true);       
    function ajaxCall(){
            $.ajax({
     url: "go.html",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#results").append(html);
     }
    });
    }
 
    });
    </script>

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working? Also, have you imported the PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile libraries?

Comment: yes i've imported them . i just showed the script code. The whole AJax call is not sent.

Comment: I understand that it is the script code but I was inquiring what / where it was failing. Is the ajaxCall() method being fired at all? Also, is the url actually "go.html"? I thought you were getting the records with PHP.

Comment: tried to log something from the inside of the ajaxCall and its logged in the Console. But when i tried to log something from the inside of .ajax() method it gave me parse error in the console. yeah actually i simplified it to find where's the error once i find it and then i'll replace it with the PHP file so its just a dummy HTML file and yet its not working